# How do I establish a peer connection inside a room with socket.io-p2p?

Tags: node.js, sockets, server, socket.io, p2p

I'm storing my connections withing arrays and I have a button (not included here) which when clicked, places the first two connections inside a room.
I want to establish a p2p connection between those two and transfer some random text or an alert over p2p.
Does anyone have an idea on how I should do that?
Note that I'm loading the socket.io-p2p script in the html so that I don't have to use browserify in this case.

client file:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost:8000/js"></script>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io('http://localhost:8000');



            var p2p = new P2P(socket);




            socket.on('C1Trigger', function (data) {
                document.getElementById("A").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            });

            socket.on('C2Trigger', function (data) {
                document.getElementById("A").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            });

            socket.on('C1BYellowTrigger', function (data) {
                document.getElementById("B").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            });

            socket.on('C2BGreenTrigger', function (data) {


                document.getElementById("B").style.backgroundColor = "green";


            });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="A">A</div>
        <div id="B">B</div>

    </body>
    <style>
        div {
            background-color: #FF0000;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 30px 60px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 60px;
        }
    </style>

    </html>
```

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
//P2P Requirements
var p2p = require('socket.io-p2p-server').Server;
io.use(p2p);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client.html');
});

app.get('/js', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/socketiop2p.min.js');
});






clients = [];
clientSockets = [];






io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  clientSockets.push(socket);




  console.log('Client: ' + socket.id + ' connected.');



  clients.push(socket.id);
  io.sockets.emit('clients', clients);
  // console.log(clients);


  socket.on('executeC1', function () {
    console.log('C1 in MainRoom pinged!');
    io.to(clients[0]).emit('C1Trigger');

  });

  socket.on('executeC2', function () {
    console.log('C2 in MainRoom pinged!');
    io.to(clients[1]).emit('C2Trigger');
  });

  socket.on('greenifyBC2', function () {
    io.to(clients[1]).emit('GreenifyTrigger');
  });

  socket.on('executeC1C2', function (data) {


    console.log('C1C2 in MainRoom pinged!');

    clientSockets[0].join('room C1C2', () => {
    //expand with features
    });
    clientSockets[1].join('room C1C2', () => {
    //expand with features
    });


    io.to(clients[0]).emit('C1BYellowTrigger');

    io.to(clients[1]).emit('C2BGreenTrigger');




    console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms);



  });




  socket.on('disconnect', function () {

    console.log('Client: ' + socket.id + ' disconnected');

    var index = clients.indexOf(socket.id);

    if (index > -1) {
      clients[index] = undefined;
    }
    console.log(clients);

  });
});

http.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use your socket.io rooms to establish a signal for webrtc. Then I would use [webrtc](https://webrtc.org/) for the p2p connection.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I am trying to figure out the same thing. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-p2p) The trick is to use tell the P2P Server to do signaling in rooms for the newly connected socket in the on('connection') of the server code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  clients[socket.id] = socket
  var room = findOrCreateRoom() //create a room (needs a property called name)
  socket.join(room.name) // join the socket
  
  p2pserver(socket, null, room) //tell the P2P server to have that socket signal to other
  // sockets in the room and not on the common namespace.
})
```

Hopefully this will help people find that part of the documentation.

I am trying to figure out how to start signaling only after sockets people are in a room. So not immediately on connection. Not sure how to "pause" signaling...

**Update**
`socket.io-p2p` https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-p2p is no longer maintained, and thus is no longer compatible with required npm packages. Use another P2P library.